# PHP Form in JQuery ColourBox

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to implement popup search window in a PHP project. I included JQuery and [ColorBox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) & have managed to open the Search popup inline (using ColorBox plugin).

This is my code to open popup window

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, transition:'none',speed:'10', close:'close', opacity:'0.6'});
});
```

Popup div has a separate `<form>` element to POST data.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnSearch']))
{
    //Code to search data
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
//Some Page Content
<div class="input"><input type="submit" name="btnSearch" Value="Search"
    class="button"></div>
</form>
```

The problem is when I click the 'Search' button it POST the form but closes the popup. How can I retain popup window opened even after the button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is what you're looking for. jQuery has built in AJAX support which you can read about [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

It's real easy to use so you shouldn't have any problems implementing it

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, Added AJAX support, now it does not close the popup, but can't use 'isset($_POST['btnSearch'])', issset with Input Texts works fine !.

Comment: @Nalaka526 - since you've changed to AJAX you'll probably have to do some modifications to your PHP code but it shouldn't be that big a change. Search google for jQuery AJAX tutorials and you should get your site running perfectly in no time